# Использование data на php и mysql

Tags: php, mysql

На странице добавляются новости и записываются в базу данных, я хочу, чтоб при записи материала в базу автоматически добавлялась дата и время публикации, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении в базу, в запросе пишем:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (comment, date) VALUES ('$comment',NOW())");
```

**NOW()** - и будет добавлять текущее время. Только ж само поле для даты не забудьте ))

Comment: да я в таблице создал поле data назначил ему тип DATATIME, правильно?

Comment: Абсолютно. Только data и date немного разные вещи )) Хотя, если это только название поля, то не имеет значения

Comment: спасибо все получилось

Comment: mysql_query("... '$comment'...");

:-\

Comment: @shurik, и что бы это значило? ))

Comment: То, что значения нужно экранировать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так, будет автоматически добавляться дата создания в поле created:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN created TIMESTAMP DEAFULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

P.S. Старайтесь не использовать в именах таблиц/полей условно зарезервированные слова, например DATE :)